# How to do a WHILE with condition of a subfield

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to do a while and display the contents in a 3 columns li.
So far so good, but I want to condition to only apear words that start with letter A, or B, or C.

The problem is that I only managed to create the condition to create the **li**, and because of this, the code is creating empty fields.
So **my question is** if there is a way to create this condition in the **while**.

**My code** [*UPDATED*][*UPDATED TO A WORKING VERSION*]

```
if( have_rows('insert_breed_name_to_add') ){
$count = 0;
while( have_rows('insert_breed_name_to_add') ){

    the_row();

    if(get_sub_field('breed_name')[0] == 'A' ){

            $count++;
            // If it is first time create "col-4"
            if($count == 1 || $count%3 == 1){ ?>
            <div class="col-4"><ul>
            <?php } ?>

            <!-- Create Li -->
            <li><?php the_sub_field('breed_name'); ?></li>

             <!-- close col-4 -->
            <?php if ($count%3 == 0){?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php }
        }
     }
  }

?>
```

Comment: First of all, `$count = 1;` is getting initialized inside the loop, should be outside right?

Comment: Thanks @Antonis , I think so, otherwise it will wrap each li in a col. I'll try to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to do but look at the below :

```
<?php

if( have_rows('insert_breed_name_to_add') ){
    $count = 0;
    while( have_rows('insert_breed_name_to_add') ){

        the_row();

        // If it starts from A or B or C
        if(get_sub_field('breed_name')[0] == 'A' || get_sub_field('breed_name')[0] == 'B' || get_sub_field('breed_name')[0] == 'C'){

                $count++;
                // If it is first time create "col-4"
                if($count == 1){ ?>
                <div class="col-4"><ul>
                <?php } ?>

                <!-- Create Li -->
                <li><?php the_sub_field('breed_name'); ?></li>

                 <!-- close col-4 -->
                <?php if ($count%3 == 0){?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php }


        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Antonis ! It was almost that! I just change  bit and its working the way I wanted. This way it is generating 3 columns of 3 and when reaches the 3th it goes down one line and continues there. Perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php if( have_rows('insert_breed_name_to_add') ):
    while( have_rows('insert_breed_name_to_add') **MAYBE INSERT CONDITION HERE? BUT HOW?** ): the_row();
while (have_rows('your_custom_field_values') ): the_row();
    $count = 1;
    if ($count%3 == 1)
    {?>
     <div class="col-4"><ul>
     <?php } ?>
     <? if( get_sub_field('breed_name')[0] == 'a' OR get_sub_field('breed_name')[0] == 'A'){ ?>
     <li><?php the_sub_field('breed_name'); ?></li>
      <?php }?>
      <?php if ($count%3 == 0){?>
      </ul></div>
      <?php }
      $count++;
      if ($count%3 != 1)?>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Exprator 
I managed to improve the code by doing that. But Is still doing something wrong. It is getting the Words starting with A but also one word with B. It's strange... Do you think as Antonis Tsimourtos said, the count should be out? Because I tried and it breaks.